# Can't auto play YouTube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, embed

I'm trying to get a Youtube video to play automatically when a user clicks this link:

```
<a class="videoLink" href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBg_G-_zOf0&rel=0&autoplay=1" rel="lightbox"></a>
```

This opens and displays the video in a lightbox (I am using SwipeBox) but **does not** autoplay the video.

The **'&rel=0'** works fine, no suggested videos are shown after the video **(it will not work if I use '?rel=0')**. But the **'&autoplay=1'** does not work at all. I have tried using **'?autoplay=1'** but that gives me a JSON error (something to do with having multiple "?'s" in the URL).

This is the code of the YouTube video when it is open within the lightbox:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/CBg_G-_zOf0?rel=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

As you can see, the **'autoplay'** is set to **'0'** which is no good. If I change the value to **'1'** in developer tools the video refreshes and automatically plays as expected.

Any suggestions on how I could possibly force the autoplay value in the iframe to be 1 would be awesome.

Comment: Yeah, that's a thing with multiple ?. With ? you start the parameter sections and with & you separate your parameter. Still searching for your real problem.

Comment: Post a fully testable code example or link that shows your problem in action within context of SwipeBox. Y'know.. something that be tested / fixed in a JS Fiddle or W3Schools' Try-It-Out section. This will get you faster help than if users have to seek out `SwipeBox.css` etc. Meet us halfway...